# Button from another class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a Fragment class with the following code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        String[] lista_nazwisk = {"Krzysztof ", "Bartłomiej ", "Kamil "};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista_nazwisk);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;

    }
```

And the code of ButtonCreator is

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;

public class ButtonCreator extends Activity {

    ImageButton add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar
      if it is present
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } */
}
```

What else I need to do to make the button works?

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: @Nilesh I've got a Fragment with list and the "add_button". I want the button code in another class and pin-up it to the Fragment.

Comment: Whats the question here? Is the button not showing the toast message when you click on it?  Or do you want to know how to implement the actual add functionality for the list when you click on the button?

Comment: then pass view object to class and do  your work .Don't make activity for that as button is in same layout  of Fragment

Comment: @Naveed yes, the button is not showing the messege, it doesn't work at all.
There's even no action in logcat when I'm clicking on it and his code is: http://pastebin.com/TSq3MmTW I created a ButtonCreator class to make action with it, but I can't correctly add it to HomeFragment.java. btw. should it be in onCreate or in onCreateView?

Comment: It seems like your ui is in the fragment but button creator is an activity where you are setting the listener.  You should add your fragment to the activity and then set the click listener in the onCreateView of the fragment.